# Linux locked processes and files

Tags: ubuntu, locking

I opened Firefox and Eclipse in Ubuntu and then selected "Lock/Switch Account".

Then I shutted down the system by pushing the button in the desktop box.

Then I opened my machine and my Firefox program will not open -- it says that a firefox process is already running. Also, when I open Eclipse I have to select a different workspace folder because the default one is already being used.

I restarted the pc and I still get this error.

Do you have any idea about what I should do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by going in the Firefox profile folder and erasing the .parentlock file (it is a hidden file).

Answer (score 1):

Execute in terminal.
To kill all running eclipses:

```
sudo killall -9 java
```

To kill all running FFs:

```
sudo killall -9 firefox
```